# How to include google fonts through url in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento-2.1.7

I have upgraded my project from 2.1.7 to 2.2.2. I am fixing issues and stucked in one font issue.
Earlier I included google fonts in Magento 2.1.7 through below code 
default_head_block.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <head>
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500,700,400italic,700italic|Muli:400,400italic" src_type="url"  />
  </head>
</page>
```

Please help to implement in Magento 2.2.2

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the issue.

Instead of "***href***" we need to use "***src***"

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,500,700,400italic,700italic|Muli:400,400italic" src_type="url"  />
```